# Javascript/jQuery plug-in Highcharts does not recognize my data array. Is it my syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have successfully called an ajax request to my rails db and grabbed the return data, putting each returned object's "level" and "date" values into an array within an array, or a coordinate pair in an array with my search() function (below). Next, that function calls drawChart(object_data) which should set the array within an array data to the series. Only problem is it's not working and I do not know why. The object_data array that I am putting in the chart falls in line with examples on the Highcharts website, but it does not seem to be working for some reason.

Search function:

```
function search() {
  var full_date_from = $( "#from" ).datepicker("getDate");
  var full_date_to = $( "#to" ).datepicker("getDate");

  var date_from = full_date_from.getMonth()+1 + "-" + full_date_from.getDate() + "-" + full_date_from.getFullYear();
  var date_to = full_date_to.getMonth()+1 + "-" + full_date_to.getDate() + "-" + full_date_to.getFullYear();

  $.ajax({
      url:"<%= url_for :controller => 'objects', :action => 'search' %>",
      data:'date_from=' + encodeURIComponent(date_from) + '&date_to=' + encodeURIComponent(date_to) + '&river_id=' + <%= @id %>,
      dataType: "json",
      cache:false,
      success:function (data) {
        var levels = [];
        var dates = [];
        var object_data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var dt1   = parseInt(data[i].date.substring(8,10));
          var mon1  = parseInt(data[i].date.substring(5,7));
          var yr1   = parseInt(data[i].date.substring(0,4));
          var date1 = Date.UTC(yr1, mon1-1, dt1);

          levels[i] = data[i].level;
          dates[i] = date1;
          var temp = [dates[i], levels[i]];
          object_data.push(temp);
        }

        drawChart(object_data);
      }
  });
 }
```

drawChart function:

```
function drawChart(object_data)
{
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  chart.series[0].setData(object_data);
}
```

chart initialization:

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
      },

      series: [{
          data: []
      }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written, `drawChart()` is re-initializing Highcharts on `#container` every time you call it, effectively resetting any options you would have set.

You should only have to call `$('#container').highcharts({...});` once.

Toss your empty initialization and change `drawChart()` to

```
function drawChart(object_data) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
        series: [{ data: object_data }]
    });
}
```

Comment: With this suggestion, the chart does not even show up at all anymore. If I put in hard-coded data in place for object_data it does work. If I print an alert in the drawChart() function, alert(object_data), I do see the correct data, though.

Comment: how your object_data looks like ?

Comment: object_data is an array of arrays of two values, so something like:    [[Date, double], [Date, double], etc..]